# Sign Mac Application without Mac Developer program

Tags: macos, ssl, certificate, signing

Is it possible to sign application and pass Gatekeeper using code-signing certificate from Comodo or Thawte or I need to have the Mac Developer Subscription for that purpose?

Answer (score 4):

You must be a member of the Mac Developer Program and use Apple's certificates to pass GateKeeper.  Here's the relevant part from their [developer library](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/OSXWorkflowGuide/DistributingApplicationsOutside/DistributingApplicationsOutside.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011201-CH12-SW2):

> Only Mac Developer Program members are eligible to request Developer
>   ID certificates and sign applications or installer packages using
>   them.
>
> When you enroll in the Mac Developer Program, you become the primary
>   contact for Apple and are asked to sign legal agreements. Regardless
>   whether you enroll as an individual or company, you are the team agent
>   and responsible for creating Developer ID certificates. If you enroll
>   as a company, you can add individuals to your team, but only the team
>   agent has permission to create Developer ID certificates. Developer ID
>   certificates are owned by the team not an individual.
>
> To enroll in the Mac Developer Program, go to Apple Developer Program
>   Enrollment where a web assistant guides you through the entire process
>   of enrolling. If you have not registered as an Apple Developer yet,
>   you can do so as part of enrolling in the Mac Developer Program. When
>   you are prompted to select a program, select the Mac Developer
>   Program.